# Send EDM(Electronic Direct Mail) with python from many sender email

Tags: python, gmail

I have two list of sender and recipient.
The condition is if mail needed be sent are more than 2000, I need to parse them and sent by different sender address.
So it’s a nested loop to send emails.
I’m struggling with it.

Here is my current code:

```py
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
content = MIMEMultipart()  #建立MIMEMultipart物件
content["subject"] = "***"  #郵件標題

content["from"] = '***'  #顯示的發件人
content["bcc"] = '***' #密件收件者
content.attach(MIMEText("***", 'html', 'utf-8'))  # 郵件純文字內容

import smtplib
with smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port="587") as smtp:  # 設定SMTP伺服器
    try:
        smtp.ehlo()  # 驗證SMTP伺服器
        smtp.starttls()  # 建立加密傳輸
        smtp.login("***", "***")  # 登入寄件者gmail
        smtp.send_message(content)  # 寄送郵件
        print("Complete!")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error message: ", e)
```

If any help, would be many thanks!

All the best,
Zoe_Lai